# Как считать массив чисел, разделенных не пробелами?

Tags: c++, c

У меня есть файл с текстом типа `40|55|30|101`.
Мне нужно получить массив этих чисел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если на коленке, то вот так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>//atoi()

using namespace std;

/**
 * @param fileName путь к файлу, напр. ("numbers.txt"), если файл
 * лежит в одной директории с исполняемым файлом.
 * @param n количество прочтённых чисел
 * @return массив прочтённых чисел
 */
int * readNumbers(const char * fileName, int &n) {
    char separator = '|';

    string line;
    ifstream source(fileName);
    getline(source, line);
    source.close();

    n = 0;
    string tsep = "|";
    string::size_type pos = 0;
    while ((pos = line.find(tsep, pos)) != string::npos ) {
        n++;
        pos += tsep.size();
    }
    n++;
    int * numbers = new int[n];

    stringstream line_streamed(line);
    string number;
    int i = 0;
    while (getline(line_streamed, number, separator)) {
        numbers[i] = atoi(number.c_str());
        i++;
    }

    return numbers;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int numOfNums;
    int& rnumOfNums = numOfNums;
    int * nums = readNumbers("numbers.txt", rnumOfNums);
    cout << "NUMBERS:\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfNums; i++) {
        cout << nums[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Предложу модифицировать (точнее - усложнить) - поскольку изначально максимальное количество чисел может быть неизвестно, можно добавлять все новые числа в список, с параллельнымм их подсчетом. Далее выделить память для всего массива и перенести числа туда. Работы, конечно, больше, но, кто знает, какие требования?

Comment: Да, я поленился, спасибо. Вот исправил, тут более просто, без списка, без особых выделений. Но я всё равно я извиняюсь за мой си++))

Итого: объявляем int количество_цифер, int числа[], вызываем: числа = readNumbers("путь_к_файлу", &количество_цифер). Имеем массив и его длину.

Comment: Не даете человеку подумать самому, плохо это!

Comment: \#include <string>
\#include <string.h> - что-то здесь лишнее. Память где освобождается?!! Мало того что думать не даете, так еще и не очень хорошие решения показываете...

Comment: Ну человек спрашивает весьма конкретный вопрос, это же не математическая задача) тут просто надо знать, как разбивать строку, как читать и пр. Я считаю, что лучше всего просто показать человеку полностью рабочий пример кода. string.h для strcpy и strtok функций. Про память спасибо, но подскажите - необходимо delete n сделать? И ещё Вы не заметили, что я source не закрыл, добавил source.close(), обратил на это внимание, когда вы про память сказали. )

Comment: Исправил, стало попроще без strcpy и strtok. И без перевода из string в char *.

Comment: Блин как всё сложно то ....

решение на perl:

в fileContent должно находится содержимое файла.

my @var = map{ int $_} (split(/\|/, $fileContent));

Comment: @Kremchik !!!

Да посмотрите Вы на ответ от @renegator.

Делайте все проще. KISS принцип.

Comment: @avp, к сожалению, я не смог заставить его пример работать :(

Comment: int * nums = 0;
nums = readNumbers("numbers.txt", rnumOfNums);
if(nums){
//вывод
}
delete [] nums;
return 0;

Answer (score 2):

На первобытном С:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <malloc.h>  
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  
    FILE *f;  
    int c, n, sz;  
    int *buff;

    f = fopen("d:\\numbers.txt", "rt");

    buff = NULL;
    sz = 0;
    n = 0;
    while (!feof(f)) {
        c = fgetc(f);
        if ( !isdigit(c) ) {
            buff = (int *) realloc(buff, sizeof(int) * (sz+1));
            buff[sz++] = n;
            n = 0;
        }
        else {
            n = n*10 + c - (int)'0';
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    free(buff);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Только realloc() на каждом шаге не надо делать.

И buff (результат) видимо надо вернуть, а не free() его.

Comment: Да нет тут все правильно, realloc вызывается, только когда достигнут конец очередного числа.

Comment: Да, именно о realloc() **для каждого числа** я и говорю. Надо, скажем, для каждого 1024-го (т.е. потихоньку (не каждый раз) просим у ОС дать нам  еще одну страничку памяти). Это существенно повышает эффективность на практике (конечно если чисел действительно много. На тысяче-другой не заметно будет).

Answer (score 1):

А что не получается?

1. Открыть файл.
2. Считать его в строку.
3. Разбить файл на подстроки, используя символ-разделитель как признак конца     подстроки (в вашем случае это '|').
4. Преобразовать каждую подстроку в число.

Парочка функций в помощь.

- fopen - открыть файл
- fseek - изменить текущую позицию в файле
- ftell - получить текущую позицию в файле
- fread - считать файл
- fclose - закрыть файл (не забывайте об этом!)
- malloc, calloc - выделение памяти
- free - освобождение памяти (и об этом не забывайте!!!)

Если буду какие-то конкретные вопросы, обращайтесь ;-)

Comment: А можно выделить результирующий массив в куче (сначала небольшой) и читать файл посимвольно в маленький буфер. Как только встретили разделитель, так преобразовали буфер в int (sscanf() или strtol()) и добавили его в массив. Когда место в массиве кончается, расширим  через realloc(). Следующую порцию байт из файла читаем в тот же буфер. (А вообще можно сразу вычислять int по прочтению очередного символа, тогда буфер не нужен).

Используемые функции: fopen(), fclose(), fgetc(), sscanf() (но можно и без нее), realloc(), free () (ну эта где-то, когда массив данных уже не нужен).

Comment: Можно, я ж не отрицаю, только читать все же лучше если не весь (вдруг будет метров 100 файл), то хотя бы кусками по несколько килобайт.

Comment: Вообще-то я имел в виду читать файл по одному байту (fgetc()). Наверное невнятно написал. 

Только сейчас увидел - @renegator реализовал.

Comment: Просто это не очень хорошо по одному байту считывать, сейчас этот пример не очень удачен, но все же представьте что вам нужер считать 1,4Мб с дискеты?  Она не помрет конечно, сразу, но думаю что это будет печально. Черт, захотелось попробовать сколько считываний/записей она выдержит...

Comment: Ну read() с носителя, естественно, оптимальное количество блоков. А потом из буфера fgetc() по байтику.

Comment: Побойтесь бога, весь ввод/вывод в stdio.h буферизован. см. функцию setbuf.

Comment: А я о чем ? Имеется в виду, естественно, тот read(), который **внутри** stdio (обычно он вызывается из fillbuf()).

Answer (score 1):

[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp), к сожалению я не смог заставить его пример работать :(
(4 часа назад) Kremchik

Я набросал чуть по другому те же идеи. У меня работает.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define INCR 3  // Для теста. На самом деле надо больше (1024)

int *
read_int_array (FILE *f, int *size) {
  int *res = NULL;
  int sz = 0, n = 0, c, s = 0, dig = 0;

  while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
    if (isdigit(c)) {  // вычисляем число из цифр
      s = s*10 + (c-'0');  
      dig = 1;
    } else {      // пропустим символы между числами
      if (dig) {  // предыдущий символ был последней цифрой числа
        dig = 0;
        if (n == sz)  // увеличим массив, если надо
           res = realloc(res,(sz+=INCR)*sizeof(int));
        res[n++] = s; // запомним очередное число
        s = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  if (dig) {  // Это если EOF при чтении цифр
    if (n == sz)
      res = realloc(res,sz+=INCR);
    res[n++] = s;
  }
  *size = n;  // "вернем" количество чисел в массиве
  res = realloc(res,n*sizeof(int));  // дело вкуса
  return res;
}

int main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  if (ac < 2) {
    fprintf (stderr,"Usage: %s filename\n",av[0]);
    exit(1);
  }
  FILE *f = fopen(av[1],"r");
  if (!f) {
    perror(av[1]);
    exit(2);
  }

  int n, *res = read_int_array(f,&n);

  fclose(f);

  printf ("read %d numbers\n",n);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i%10 == 0) putchar('\n');
    printf ("%d ",res[i]);
  }
  putchar('\n');

  if (res) free (res);
  printf ("End\n");
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Вот этот вариант зачётный. Кстати 1024 от 3 отличается 10% приростом производительности, а вот если поставить 10.000, то аж 70%. Мой вариант отказывается работать с файлами в районе 500 Кб (около 100.000 чисел) а Ваш нет. Круто.

Comment: @Kremchik прям теряюсь в догадках, что именно в моем коде отказалось работать

Comment: @renegator Ну для меня это тоже вопрос :) Могу только сказать, что я сам вставил цикл распечатки чисел после строчки fclose и перед free - он ничего не печатает. n равна 0.

Comment: n и должно равняться нулю. размер массива считается в sz

int i;
for( i = 0; i < sz; printf("%d ", buff[i++]));

Comment: @renegator Ваш код будет работать, **только в случае ОДНОГО разделителя** между числами.

Comment: @avp я вполне отдаю себе в этом отчет

Comment: изменение такое
    
 i = 0;
 while (!feof(f)) {
  c = fgetc(f);
  if ( !isdigit(c) ) {
   if ( i ) {
    buff = (int *) realloc(buff, sizeof(int) * (sz+1));
    buff[sz++] = n;
    n = 0;
    i = 0;
   }
  }
  else {
   n = n*10 + c - (int)'0';
   i++;
  }
 }

Comment: Согласен, завязываться на константу EOF - опасно. Вообще напоминаю, что 'я' в ДОСовской кодировке и получается 0xff, т.е. EOF, т.е. файл будет криво обрабатываться (даже текстовый). Поэтому правильный вариант проверки конца файла - вызывать ф-цию `feof()`

Comment: Не бойтесь завязываться на константу EOF.

 Это опасно, только если **читать неправильно**, т.е. в **char , а надо в int !!! **. При чтении в int 'я' будет 255 (это в кодировке cp-1251 Windows, а в ДОС кодировка cp-866) , а не -1 (EOF). 

Собственно, это описано в документации.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сказать потоку что `|` это пробельный символ, и считать числа как будто они разделены пробелами.

Для этого надо сделать свой тип-facet, проще всего на базе `std::ctype<char>`, и задать потоку новую локаль с этим facet.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <locale>
#include <cstring>

struct PipeAsSpace : std::ctype<char> {
    PipeAsSpace() : ctype(init_table()) {}

    const mask* init_table() {
        std::memcpy(table, classic_table(), table_size); // копируем стандартную таблицу
        table['|'] |=  space; // и говорим что '|' это пробел
        return table;
    }

    mask table[table_size];
};

int main() {
    std::istringstream stream("40|55|30|101");

    // устанавливаем новую локаль с нашим Facet
    stream.imbue(std::locale(stream.getloc(), new PipeAsSpace));

    // читаем числа в вектор
    std::istream_iterator<int> begin(stream), end;
    std::vector<int> arr(begin, end);

    for (auto x : arr) std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

Comment: А почему не getline с сепаратором? Выглядит концептуально проще.

Comment: Хм. Ну это да, согласен. Хотя выглядит как-то слишком сложно для такой простой задачи, как на мой вкус.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int x[4];
  string s;
  ifstream fi("input_file.txt");
  ofstream fo("buf_file.txt");//уж как придумал!
  getline(fi, s);
  /*сначала поток, потом переменная-не перепутай(я сначала перепутал))*/
  for (int i = 0; i <= s.size(); i++)
  {
   if (s[i]!='|')
     fo << s[i];
   else
     fo << endl;
  }
  fi.close();
  fo.close();
  fi.open("buf_file.txt");
  for (int i=0; i<=3; i++)
  {
    fi>>x[i];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: а и в конце не забудь вывести на экран числа или что там надо

Comment: Неоптимально. Существенно более интересный вариант - использование stringstream.

Comment: я наверное этого еще не изучил)