# Поиск символа в строке С++

Tags: c++, символы

Никак не разберусь с символами. Есть задание - массив (вообще файл, но это не важно) со словами. Надо выбрать все слова, содержащие в  себе символы, не являющиеся буквами или цифрами (!@#$%^&* и тд). Долго лазил по интернетам, в итоге написал такой код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        char s[] = "d152313", *ps = s; //массив со словами
        bool a = false;                //флаг, говорящий о найденном символе

        char au;

        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {              //цикл выводит в консоли
            au = i; cout << i << "\t" << au << endl; //символы и их коды
        }

// 48-57 цифры
// 65-90   A-Z
// 97-122  a-z
// 128-175 А-п
// 224-241 р-ё 
        while (ps = strchr(ps, 51)) {   //проверяем массив на наличие цифры 3
            if (ps != NULL) { a = true; }
            std::cout << ps++ - s + 1 << "\n"; //выводим место тройки (троек) в массиве 
        }

        if (a == true) { std::cout << "PROFIT"; }
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

В данном случае он проверяет массив на наличие тройки и говорит что она найдена. Вопрос такой - как мне проверить диапазон (а конкретно сейчас надо бы проверить на несоответствие 5ти диапазонам, если 48-57, 65-90 и так далее, то ничего не делать, в противном случае флаг на true)? И вообще то чем я занимаюсь не совсем в край уже похабно? я только учусь, пока тяжело. Очень надеюсь на то, что описал всё нормально, и мне помогут, прежде чем удалят тему)

Comment: Думаю, вам стоит отойти от функций поиска (strchr и т.п.) и проверять каждый байт на принадлежность к искомым диапазонам.

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться, как именно проверить байты? я не совсем понял, что вы имеете ввиду

Answer (score 1):

Для классификации символов следует использовать функции `std::isalpha`, `std::isdigit`, либо из `<locale>`, либо из `<cctype>`.

Если считать что слова - это последовательности символов, разделенных пробельными символами (`\t\r\n`), то проще всего использовать `std::istream`. Однако пунктуация тоже будет считаться частью слова, например `"abc,"`. Это можно исправить если добавить пунктуацию в список пробельных символов, [как это сделано тут для '|'](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/477977/177684).

Пример с функциями из `<locale>`:

```
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

std::locale locale(".866");
bool is_word(char c) {
  return std::isalpha(c, locale) || std::isdigit(c, locale);
}

int main() {
                           // "это текст;" CP866
  std::stringstream stream("\xed\xe2\xae \xe2\xa5\xaa\xe1\xe2; ab1 c@d qw? xyz rs.");
  std::string word;
  while (stream >> word) {
    if (!std::all_of(begin(word), end(word), is_word)) {
      std::cout << '[' << word << "]\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Аналогичный код с `<cctype>`

```
#include <clocale> // не путать с <locale>
#include <cctype>

bool is_word(char c) {
  auto uc = static_cast<unsigned char>(c);  // см. ниже
  return std::isalpha(uc) || std::isdigit(uc);
}

int main() {
  std::setlocale(LC_ALL, ".866");
                           // "это текст;" CP866
  std::stringstream stream("\xed\xe2\xae \xe2\xa5\xaa\xe1\xe2; ab1 c@d qw? xyz rs.");
  ... далее как в коде выше
```

Тут надо обратить внимание, что символы надо преобразовывать в `unsigned char`, потому что иначе в `std::isdigit(int)` попадет отрицательное значение, а это приводит к неопределенному поведению.

---

Функции `<ctypes>` работают только однобайтовых кодировок, и не работают для многобайтовых, например UTF-8. То же справедливо и для функций `<locale>` - хотя там есть поддержка `wchar_t`, но эти функции принимают только один символ, а значит не полностью поддерживают UTF-16. Также стандартные локали не имеют полной поддержки юникода, по этому например не все символы-цифры будут классифицированы как цифры (`一二三１２３`).

Answer (score 0):

При проверке соответствия символом не стоит переходить на сравнение их кодов, т.к. в разных кодировках разные символы могут иметь разные числовые коды.
Для проверки символа на принадлежность к буквам есть стандартная функция [`std::isalpha`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/), к цифрам - [`std::isdigit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/). На них и следует опираться при принятии решения.

Comment: @Abyx std::isdigit тоже. Принципиальный момент - использование переносимых стандартных функций, а не оперирование кодами символов явно.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам действительно нужен ответ на C++, то решение Вашей задачи выглядит примерно [**так**](http://ideone.com/0ti1WU):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "The quick br1own f@ox jumps over t-he lazy dog.";
    std::istringstream iss(str, std::istringstream::in);
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    while( iss >> str ) words.push_back(str);
    for(auto&x:words)
    {
        for(size_t i=0; i<x.size(); i++)
        {
            if(!std::isdigit(x[i]) && !std::isalpha(x[i]))
            {
                std::cout << x <<std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Это код выводит только те слова, где кроме цифр и букв встречаются другие символы. Но основная проблема, Вы столкнетесь - это русские буквы (да и любые другие, отличные от латиницы). Указанный у Вас диапазон для русских букв верен только, для определенной кодовой страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Читайте код с комментариями:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
// Вернет истину если в слове есть специальные символы
bool IsInWordNotAlphaAndDigit(string s){
    for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); it++)
        if (!isalnum(*it))
            return true;

    return false;
}

int main(){
    string str = "abc 111 ab1 ab$ a1&   1ab a&b a1b", buf;
    vector<string> vstr; // сюда мы будем ложить найденные слова

    str.push_back(' '); // чтобы не думать о последней итерации

    // пробежимся циклом по символам строки
    for (auto it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); it++){
        if (*it != ' '){ // если не пробел добавить в буффер
            buf.push_back(*it);
        } else {
            if (buf != "") // если буффер не пуст
                vstr.push_back(buf); // найден пробел добавить буфер в массив

            buf.clear(); // очистить буфер под следующее слово
        }
    }

    // пробежимся циклом по словам в массиве
    for (auto it = vstr.begin(); it != vstr.end(); it++){
        if (IsInWordNotAlphaAndDigit(*it)){ // если в слове есть специальные символы
            cout << *it << endl;            // вывести слово на экран
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

вывод:

[image: result]